# jquery expand collapse div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code that I have works if the "mer info" div is inside of the "exp_container ex_collapsed" div.
What I want is to move the div that trigger the expand/collapse function to another div

```
<div class="col-xs-2 padding_left div_center_text">
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< --- want "mer info" div function here >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  </div>


  <div class="row row_no_margin">
    <div class="col-md-12 ">


          <div class="exp_container exp_collapsed">
            <div class="exp_header text_ads_expand_button_mer_info">Mer info</div>
            <div class="exp_content">
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-3 ">
                 <%= image_tag(ads_item.logo_path) %><br><br>
```

Comment: Add a (maybe even not working) example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and people will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add just 2 lines of code for collapse and hide of the div.

```
$('.exp_collapsed').click(function(){
    $('.text_ads_expand_button_mer_info').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Check out the working code:

```js
$('.exp_collapsed').click(function() {
  $('.text_ads_expand_button_mer_info').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.text_ads_expand_button_mer_info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-2 padding_left div_center_text">
  <div class="exp_container exp_collapsed"><a href="#">Expand</a>
    <div class="exp_header text_ads_expand_button_mer_info">Mer info
      <div class="exp_content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 ">Content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm. One thing that I notice is that I first enter the site and click on the text for the expanding fucntion it won't work so I need to reload the page again and then it works. that happens all the time.

That also happens if I go to another link and then go back to the page that has the fucntion and it wont work then either.

Comment: this is the code that worked for me

'
$(function(){
  $('.exp_header').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.exp_container').toggleClass('exp_collapsed');
  });
  
});'

Comment: hi, I have just tried your answer and it works just fine thanks